# pagination in php and keeping results

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

have tried to implement a pagination script in my php code (adopted from a sample code i found on the net)
the page returns resaults of a mysql query. the default is an empty 'keyword' which returns all data from databse. 
succeeded as far as pagination works when all data is returned but when i filter results through a keyword search clicking 'next page' returns the next page in unfiltered results (ie the searched keyword is lost in the refresh)

this is the relevant code (hope it makes sense):

> Blockquote
>
> ```
>     $txt1='<A HREF="/memimomedia/music/128kb/';
>     $txt2='" ><IMG src="/Save.png" width="24" height="24" align="middle" border="0"></A>';
>
>     $txt9a='<a href="';
>     $txt9b='" target="_blank">';
>     $txt9c='</a>';
>
>     $txt10a='<audio src="./128kb/';        
>     $txt10d='" controls></audio>';
>
>
> if(empty($_POST['searchkeywords']) && empty($_GET['searchkeywords']))     { $result = mysql_query("SELECT *
> ```
>
> FROM ppl_tracks WHERE Mixed !='0' ORDER BY Track"); }
>       if(!empty($_GET['searchkeywords']))   { $Searchword=$_GET['searchkeywords']; }
>
> ```
> if(!empty($_POST['searchkeywords']))  { $Searchword=$_POST['searchkeywords']; }
> ```
>
> $Totalresults = mysql_query("SELECT Track FROM (ppl_tracks LEFT JOIN
>   TrackStyle ON ppl_tracks.RECNO = TrackStyle.TrackID LEFT JOIN
>   StyleTable ON TrackStyle.StyleID = StyleTable.ID) LEFT JOIN TrackMood
>   ON ppl_tracks.RECNO = TrackMood.TrackID LEFT JOIN MoodTable ON
>   TrackMood.MoodID = MoodTable.ID WHERE (MoodChoices LIKE
>   '%$Searchword%' OR Description LIKE '%$Searchword%' OR StyleChoices
>   LIKE '%$Searchword%' OR Tempo LIKE '%$Searchword%' OR Track LIKE
>   '%$Searchword%' ) AND Mixed =true GROUP BY Track ORDER BY Track" );
>
> //This checks to see if there is a page number. If not, it will set it
>   to page 1     if(isset($_GET['pagenum'])) { $pagenum =
>   $_GET['pagenum']; } else { $pagenum = 1; }
>
> //Here we count the number of results
>        $hits = mysql_num_rows($Totalresults);
>
> //This is the number of results displayed per page 
>        $page_hits = 15;
>
> //This tells us the page number of our last page 
>        $last = ceil($hits/$page_hits);
>
> //this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our
>   maximum pages 
>        if ($pagenum < 1) 
>         { 
>            $pagenum = 1; 
>         } 
>        elseif ($pagenum > $last) 
>         { 
>            $pagenum = $last; 
>         }
>
> //This sets the range to display in our query 
>        $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_hits .',' .$page_hits;
>
> $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (ppl_tracks LEFT JOIN TrackStyle
>   ON ppl_tracks.RECNO = TrackStyle.TrackID LEFT JOIN StyleTable ON
>   TrackStyle.StyleID = StyleTable.ID) LEFT JOIN TrackMood ON
>   ppl_tracks.RECNO = TrackMood.TrackID LEFT JOIN MoodTable ON
>   TrackMood.MoodID = MoodTable.ID WHERE (MoodChoices LIKE
>   '%$Searchword%' OR Description LIKE '%$Searchword%' OR StyleChoices
>   LIKE '%$Searchword%' OR Tempo LIKE '%$Searchword%' OR Track LIKE
>   '%$Searchword%' ) AND Mixed =true GROUP BY Track ORDER BY Track $max"
>   );
>
> echo "  Track -
>   Artist Description Download  ";
>
> $color="1";
>
> while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   { $SelectedStyles =
>   array(); $Track=$row['Track']; $SelectedStylesQuery = mysql_query("
>   SELECT StyleChoices FROM ppl_tracks LEFT JOIN TrackStyle ON
>   ppl_tracks.RECNO = TrackStyle.TrackID LEFT JOIN StyleTable ON
>   TrackStyle.StyleID = StyleTable.ID WHERE ppl_tracks.Track='$Track'");
>   while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($SelectedStylesQuery)) {
>       $SelectedStyles[] = $row1[StyleChoices]; } $SelectedMoods = array(); $SelectedMoodsQuery = mysql_query(" SELECT MoodChoices FROM
>   ppl_tracks LEFT JOIN TrackMood ON ppl_tracks.RECNO = TrackMood.TrackID
>   LEFT JOIN MoodTable ON TrackMood.MoodID = MoodTable.ID WHERE
>   ppl_tracks.Track='$Track'"); while($row2 =
>   mysql_fetch_array($SelectedMoodsQuery)) {
>       $SelectedMoods[] = $row2[MoodChoices]; } sort($SelectedMoods); sort($SelectedStyles); $stringS= implode(", ", $SelectedStyles);
>   $stringM= implode(", ", $SelectedMoods);
>
> if($color==1) {  echo "";  echo "" . $row['Track'] . " - " .
>   ucwords($row['Artist']) . "";  echo "" . $stringM .
>   "
> ".$stringS."";  echo "" . $txt1.$row['FileName'].$txt2 .
>   "";  echo "" . $txt10a.$row['FileName'].$txt10d.""; 
>   echo "";  $color="2"; }
>
> else {  echo "";  echo "" . $row['Track'] . " - " .
>   ucwords($row['Artist']) . "";  echo "" . $stringM .
>   "
> ".$stringS."";  echo "" . $txt1.$row['FileName'].$txt2 .
>   "";  echo "" . $txt10a.$row['FileName'].$txt10d.""; 
>   echo "";  $color="1";}
>
> } echo "";
>
> // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of
>   pages
>
> echo " --Page $pagenum of $last--
>
> ";    // First we check if we
>   are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous
>   page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate
>   links to the first page, and to the previous page.
>
> if ($pagenum == 1)
>
> {
>
> }
>
> else
>
> {  echo "  <<-First ";
>   echo "  -   ";  $previous = $pagenum-1;  echo "  <-Previous ";  }
>
> $counter=1; while ( $counter <= $last ) 
>           {
>         if ($counter==$pagenum) 
>           {
>         echo " - ";
>         echo " $counter ";
>         echo " - ";
>           }
>
> ```
>   else
>
>     {
>   echo " - ";
>   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$counter'>$counter</a> ";
>   echo " - ";
>     } $counter = $counter + 1; }
> ```
>
> //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last
>   page, and then generating the Next and Last links
>
> if ($pagenum == $last)
>
> {
>
> }
>
> else {  $next = $pagenum+1;  echo " Next -> ";  echo "   -
>   ";  echo " Last ->>
>   ";  }  mysql_close($con); ?>

Comment: Please make an effort to format your code. This is unreadable

Answer (score 3):

You are reloading the page every time you go onto a new page, so you need to pass the search term into the page again. The easiest way to do this is to update your link for pagination to the following:

```
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?searchkeywords=" . $_REQUEST["searchkeywords"] . "&pagenum=$counter'>$counter</a> ";
```

$_REQUEST will handle both $_POST and $_GET variables, but you may want to do this in your own way. Simply put you just need to pass the searchkeywords back into your url